# Type Observable<MyData> is not assignable to MyData

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class MyClass {
    data: MyData;  
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {    
      this.data = this.dataService.getData(); // error             
    }
}


export class DataService{
    data: MyData; 
     constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getData(): Observable<MyData>{
       return Observable.from([this.fakeData()]
          .map(res=>res as MyData));
    }   

    private fakeData() : MyData {   
       ...  
    }
}
```

I'm getting error on line

```
 this.data = this.dataService.getData()
```

> Type Observable is not assignable to MyData

Comment: But you return Observable. What are you expecting? `this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data=> this.data = data })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: this question is just so...not smart

Comment: haha, I guess you are the smart one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is right.

In your component, you said that `data` is supposed to be a `MyData` object.
Then, in your constructor you call your service that returns an `Observable` of `MyData` and you try to assign its result to your attribute `data`.

That's not how Observable works.

Here, you have two simple solutions :

### Subscribing to your observable

```
export class MyClass {
    data: MyData;  
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {    
      this.dataService.getData().subscribe((myData) => {
        this.data = myData;
      });  
    }
}
```

### Or using the [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your template

```
export class MyClass {
    data$: Observable<MyData>; // Change the type here.
    // The $ suffix is a convention to tell that
    // this attribute is an observable.

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {    
      this.data$ = this.dataService.getData();  
    }
}
```

And then, in your template you can use `data` with the [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

```
<div>
    <some-component [someData]="data$ | async"></some-component>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't vote down but using first approach I'm getting Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type MyData

Comment: Ah right, I didn't remove the assignation, sorry. I forget to add a $ also. Updated !

Comment: How can I apply async pipe on <input required [(ngModel)]="data.firstName> ?

Comment: You can't directly. But you can split the binding from the change event. `<input [ngModel]="data$ | async" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">`. The "banana in a box" syntax `[(ngModel)]` is just a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

try this, declare data as observable of MyData

```
export class MyClass {
  data: Observable<MyData>;   
 constructor(private dataService: DataService) {    
   this.data = this.dataService.getData(); // error             
 }
}
```